# Terraform With Resource Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create cloudwatch alert of Auto scaling group using terraform. I have used terraform module with github source for cloudwatch alert.

My code for provisioning Auto scaling group is:

```
   resource "aws_launch_configuration" "main" {
     name_prefix          = "${format("%s-%s-postgres-", var.name, var.environment)}"
     instance_type        = "${var.instance_type}"
     image_id             = "${var.ami}"
     key_name             = "${var.key_name}"
     iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.server.id}"
     security_groups      = ["${var.security_groups}", "${aws_security_group.main.id}"]
     user_data            = "${data.template_file.main.rendered}"

  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = "${var.root_volume_size}"
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "main" {
  count                     = "${var.size}"
  name                      = "${var.name}-${var.environment}-postgres-asg-${count.index}"
  launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.main.name}"
  max_size                  = "${var.max_size}"
  min_size                  = "${var.min_size}"
  desired_capacity          = "${var.desired_capacity}"
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  health_check_grace_period = 600
  force_delete              = false
  load_balancers            = ["${aws_elb.main.name}"]
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${element(var.subnet_ids, count.index % length(var.subnet_ids))}"]
  termination_policies      = ["OldestLaunchConfiguration", "Default"]
  depends_on                = ["aws_launch_configuration.main"]

  tags = ["${list(
    map(
      "key", "Name",
      "value", "${var.name}-${var.environment}-postgres-${count.index}",
      "propagate_at_launch", true
    ),
    map(
      "key", "role",
      "value", "postgres",
      "propagate_at_launch", true
    ),
    map(
      "key", "LaunchConfigName",
      "value", "${aws_launch_configuration.main.name}",
      "propagate_at_launch", true
    ),
    map(
      "key", "ServerGroupIndex",
      "value", count.index,
      "propagate_at_launch", true
    ),
    map(
      "key", "Function",
      "value", "${var.name}",
      "propagate_at_launch", true
    ),
    map(
      "key", "Stage",
      "value", "${var.environment}",
      "propagate_at_launch", true
    )
  )}"]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

And Terraform code for cloudwatch alarms is:

```
module "alarm-asg-cpu" {
  source = "git::git@github.com:gruntwork-io/module-aws-monitoring.git//modules/alarms/asg-cpu-alarms?ref=v0.9.1"
  alarm_sns_topic_arns                    = ["${var.ebs_backup_sns_topic}"]
  asg_names                               = ["${aws_autoscaling_group.main.name}"]
  num_asg_names                           ="1"
  high_cpu_utilization_threshold          = "10"
  high_cpu_utilization_period             = "60"
  high_cpu_utilization_evaluation_periods = "1"
  high_cpu_utilization_statistic          = "Average"
}

module "alarm-asg-disk" {
  source = "git::git@github.com:gruntwork-io/module-aws-monitoring.git//modules/alarms/asg-disk-alarms?ref=v0.9.1"
  alarm_sns_topic_arns                     = ["${var.ebs_backup_sns_topic}"]
  asg_names                                = ["${aws_autoscaling_group.main.name}"]
  num_asg_names                            ="1"
  file_system                              = "/dev/xvdh"
  mount_path                               = "/var/lib/pgsql"
  high_disk_utilization_threshold          = "10"
  high_disk_utilization_period             = "60"
  high_disk_utilization_evaluation_periods = "1"
  high_disk_utilization_statistic          = "Maximum" 
}
```

When I run terraform plan command. it shows the following error:

[image]

I am stuck in this issue. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: All of that code is located in the same directory ? It seems the second file is called by a parent module `postgres`.

Comment: No, All this code is located in the same file named "main.tf"

Comment: @QuentinRevel I have used github source with module for cloudwatch alarms? Is this the issue of github repository?

Comment: I don't think so, I don't understand why it is not working

Comment: Where's the Postgres module that it's complaining about?

Comment: When you run `apply`, what is the output?  Has the ASG been created before the modules start creating?  TF normally does a good job of ordering dependencies but you might have to give it a hint with [dependson](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies.html#implicit-and-explicit-dependencies)

Comment: You're missing half the code.

Comment: Can you start `terraform console` and run `aws_autoscaling_group.main.name` - does it give any output?

Answer (score 0):

So you set count in resource autoscaling

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "main" {
  count                     = "${var.size}"
  ...
```

the resource will be created as below format, depend on how many count of size you set.

```
aws_autoscaling_group.main[0]
aws_autoscaling_group.main[1]
aws_autoscaling_group.main[2]
...
```

Then when you reference from `module "alarm-asg-cpu"` you need set count on it as well.

That's the reason why it can't find resource `aws_autoscaling_group.main`

But there is an open issue in terraform which you can't set `count` in module

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/953

So you need think other way to workaround it, for example, not use `count` to create resource `aws_autoscaling_group`, create them one by one